# Value in spinner in android

Tags: android

I have created a spinner widget on which the value are year from 2010 to 2014. My problem is that I want to have the value of the present year, previous year and next year. What i want to ask, is that the value should automatically changes once the year is updated. Like for example: Present year-2012, Previous year 2011, Next Year-2013. So if the year is now 2013, the Previous year should be change to 2012, present year is 2013, and next year is 2014.

Answer (score 0):

use calendar

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
int yr=cal.get(Calendar.Year);
//yr++ is next n yr-- is prev
```

Comment: So how i can put the date in an array. because I put the data only in string.xml

Comment: are you inflating spinner from xml.the you cant since data you are using is dynamic(depends on year ),so you need to use an adapter and add these dates as list or array.you can you arrayadapter.

Comment: can u show me some example on how to add like for example String[] year = {2012,2011}

Comment: how to put the date inside the braces

Comment: String presentYr=String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.Year));
int prev=present-1;
String prevYr=Integer.toString(prev);
int next=present+1;
String nxtYr=""+next;